# Jquery Airport plugin does not show non-english characters

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with jquery airport plugin and I would like to display some special characters like ø,æ,å.
I have modified the chars array in the source code. which looks like the below..

```
var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ' ', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z','-','æ', 'å', 'ø'];
```

Now the problem is my web site does not display Ø.
But in my page i have 'Ø' in some other places as well but they are displaying properly.

It is not shown properly only where I am using the plugin.

```
$('#airportText').airport(['Roskilde', 'Herning', 'København']);
```

instead of Ø, page is displaying '�'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure your script containing your chars array definition is encoded in UTF8 (without BOM). This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I saved the javascript file again using utf-8 and it works now

Answer (score 0):

This is a character-level problem. Check out what the character encoding of the file containing the code (a .js file or a .html file) is, and make it match the declared encoding. For generalities on this, see the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php).

Educated guess: The symbol '�' appears most often when an ISO−8859-1 or windows-1252 encoded file is being misinterpreted as UTF-8 encoded. If this is the case, and if the JavaScript code appears inside an HTML document, then a quick fix would be to change `utf-8` to `windows-1252` in the HTML tag that declares the encoding, such as `<meta charset="...">`. This won’t help, though, if the server announces the character encoding. Then you need to change the encoding of your file to match that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess the javascript file was not saved in utf-8 format.